# Should a RESTful API return data which is reshaped for the UI

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

Lets assume ONE team uses the API to return data to a SPA in the browser.

Is it RESTful to return data which is specially prepared for the UI of the SPA?

Instead the client could prepare the data specially with JS what many want to avoid.

WHAT means reshaped? =>

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SchoolclassCodeDTO>> GetSchoolclassCodesAsync(int schoolyearId)
{
    var schoolclassCodes = await schoolclassCodeRepository.GetSchoolclassCodesAsync(schoolyearId);
    var allPupils = schoolclassCodes.SelectMany(s => s.Pupils).Distinct<Pupil>(new PupilDistinctComparer());

    var allPupilsDTOs = allPupils.Select(p => p.ToPupilDTO());
    var schoolclassCodeDTOs = schoolclassCodes.Select(s => s.ToSchoolclassDTO());

    // Prepare data specially for UI DataGrid with checkboxes
    foreach (var s in schoolclassCodeDTOs)
    {
        foreach (var p in allPupilsDTOs)
        {
            var targetPupil = s.Pupils.SingleOrDefault(pupil => pupil.Id == p.Id);
            if(targetPupil == null)
            {
                p.IsSelected = false;
                s.Pupils.Add(p);
            }
            else
            {
                targetPupil.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return schoolclassCodeDTOs;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean *specially prepared*?

Comment: I updated the question with a code sample!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question.  Problem is, it's likely that only you have the answer.

**tl;dr** Good-old *"it's application-specific"*.

You probably need to look at this as a continuum, not a binary decision.  On one extreme you have the server generate HTML views and is thus responsible for a lot of UI concerns, on the other you have the server expose a data model with very generic CRUD functionality, and is thus not responsible for any UI concerns.  Somewhere in the middle, you can also find a design where a server interface is specific to an application but does not necessarily expose HTML (although with the magic of conn-neg everything falls into place) for possibly very obvious reasons (when it comes to so-called SPAs).

So, what should you choose?

I expect some people to advise you to decouple client and server as much as possible, but I personally believe there is no such ultimate "good practice".  In fact, it might be premature.  Design your logical components first, and *then* decide on where and how they should run.

Remember:

> A good architecture allows major decisions to be deferred and maximizes the number of decisions not made.

(Uncle Bob)

Why?  Well, because *these* (domain logic and execution environment) are truly separate concerns:  they might evolve *independently*.  For example, you might decide to create a thinner client for mobile and a thicker client for desktop if the application is compute-intensive (e.g. to save battery power).  Or, you might do the exact opposite if the application is network-intensive (e.g. to save roundtrips when connectivity is bad, also consider "offline-first").  Maybe you'll provide all variants and let the user choose, or maybe choose automatically based on available resources -- whatever the requirements warrant and however they might change.

I think these are more appropriate questions and architectural decisions to make (but again: only after you've already designed the boundaries of your logical components).  These clearer requirements will help you decide which components of your application should run where.  They will *drive* the way you *represent* your boundaries (whether they be internal or remote APIs, private or public) but not how you *shape* them (that's already done).  Your RESTful API (if you decide you need one and that a REST-style architecture is appropriate) is just a representation for an arbitrary boundary.

And that's how you will eventually answer your own question in the context of your scenario -- which should hopefully have become very intuitive by then.

End note:  While having the domain logic strictly shape your boundaries is nice and pure, it's inevitable that some concerns pertaining to the execution environment (like who controls certain network hosts, where the data should reside, etc) will feed back into the domain design.  I don't see it as a contradiction;  your application *does* influence whatever activity you're modelling, so its own concerns must be modelled too.  Tools also influence the way you think, so if HTTP is a tool and you're very good at using it, you might start using it everywhere.  This is not necessarily bad (e.g. the jury is still out on "micro-services"), though one should be aware that knowing too few tools *often* (not always) push developers to awkward corners.  How could I not finish with:  *"use the right tool for th--"* ah, it's getting old, isn't it ;).

Comment: application-specific is a good word for it. I could design my services all in that way that they are domain-specific but not client specific (wpf,desktop browser , mobile,etc...) Then each client would very probably have to do some more http requests directly to the database and composite its data on the client for the specific UI. I guess that would be the best. But on the other side very probably... desktop/mobile browser share 80% of the same data display in the UI thus using a single DTO retrieval instead of many single http requests is better. Hm... yes the right approach for t-- grr...:P